# normal map exported from Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, normal-map

Hello i'm trying to export normal maps from Blender to my own application.Below in the 1st pic you will see how the normal mapped model looks like in Blender Cycles Render mode and the 2nd model is how it looks like in my Application.
[image]
[image]

So by looking at the red circles of the 2nd pic u can see that the 2nd pic is not looking exact as the 1st pic that it's suppose to be. So i'm wondering if there's some special option or procedure to select or do in Blender before exporting and using its generated normal maps in third party applications like my indie application or is the issue looking like something completely different from a Blender Issue could someone explain?

Comment: maybe try a "32-bit float" image (when you create the image in Blende rmake sure that the option is activated), or make sure that it is set to non-color in your application?

Comment: The normal map calculated from cycles is an OpenGL normal map. Make sure "your application" supports this. Invert the green channel if the tool can only handle DirectX maps.

Comment: My Application is a C++ Opengl3-4 application. Also my image is set to non-color when created and when i re-run (re-Bake) it in Blender as a 32-bit float image it made no difference in my Application after exporting. Thanks for the attempted assists very much though